# Get indices of items in numpy array, where values is in list

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a numpy way (and without for loop) to extract all the indices in a numpy array `list_of_numbers`, where values are in a list `values_of_interest`?

This is my current solution:

```py
list_of_numbers = np.array([11,0,37,0,8,1,39,38,1,0,1,0])
values_of_interest = [0,1,38]

indices = []
for value in values_of_interest:
    this_indices = np.where(list_of_numbers == value)[0]
    indices = np.concatenate((indices, this_indices))

print(indices) # this shows [ 1.  3.  9. 11.  5.  8. 10.  7.]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `numpy.where` with `numpy.isin`:

```
np.argwhere(np.isin(list_of_numbers, values_of_interest)).ravel()
```

Output:

```
array([ 1,  3,  5,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])
```

Comment: Had to search a single value in a numpy array which has 2 distinct values. So np.isin gave [True, False] or [False,True].  but was struggling around, didn't know how to get the exact index of True. Thanks!