# Replace values in numpy array equal to list of values

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array - image with various values:
example
image = [1 ,2 ,2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4,
5, 6, 6 ,7 ,8 ,8 ,8 ,8]
I want to replace only those numbers occurring less than twice - by a specific number, let's say 0.
I managed to create the list of those numbers like this:

```
(unique, counts) = np.unique(image, return_counts=True)
frequencies = np.asarray((unique, counts)).T
freq = frequencies[frequencies[:,1] < 2,0]
print(freq)
array([1, 3, 5, 7], dtype=int64)
```

How do I replace those numbers by zero?

the outcome should look like :
[0 ,2 ,2, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4,
0, 6, 6 ,0 ,8 ,8 ,8 ,8]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If both `image` and `freq` are numpy arrays:

```
freq = np.array([1, 3, 5, 7])
image = np.array([1 ,2 ,2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6 ,7 ,8 ,8 ,8 ,8])
```

---

**Solution 1**

You can then find the indices of `image` entries appearing in `freq`, then set them to zero:

```
image[np.argwhere(np.isin(image, freq)).ravel()] = 0
```

Based on: [Get indices of items in numpy array, where values is in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63949141/get-indices-of-items-in-numpy-array-where-values-is-in-list).

---

**Solution 2**

Use `np.in1d`:

```
image = np.where(np.in1d(image,freq),0,image)
```

More info: [Numpy - check if elements of a array belong to another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37913957/numpy-check-if-elements-of-a-array-belong-to-another-array)

---

**Solution 3**

You can also use a list comprehension:

```
image = [each if each not in freq else 0 for each in image]
```

Can find more info here: [if/else in a list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension).

---

The last one will result in a list, not a numpy array, but other than that, all of these yield the same result.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response works like a charm with the example, but with my image I get: "\ipykernel_launcher.py:4: DeprecationWarning:

elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future."
I checked the image and the values stayed as in the original

Comment: Rewritten my answer, removing the confusing thing about `res`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I tried all of them. But none of them works as I expected. I guess it worked for the first row of the image though. The image is about 500 rows by 500 cols, sorry for not clarifying this sooner

Comment: Oh, your `image` array is multidimensional? Sadly this means that these solutions aren't  going to work.

Comment: I recommend asking a new question emphasizing that arrays are multidimensional, with arrays similar to your real arrays (ie they should have the same number of dimensions) - other people are probably going to assume what I did unless they are reading these comments.

Answer (score 0):

You could compare each item to the rest of the array to form a 2D matrix and sum each count.  Then assign the items meeting the frequency condition with the desired value:

```
import numpy as np

img = np.array([1 ,2 ,2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6 ,7 ,8 ,8 ,8 ,8])

img[np.sum(img==img[:,None],axis=1)<2] = 0

array([0, 2, 2, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 6, 6, 0, 8, 8, 8, 8])
```

Probably not very efficient but it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Very efficient, but if I wanted to set the number to "0" or "nan", would that be possible?

Comment: Changed it to a masked assignment, you can use any value you want in that form.

Comment: This worked like a charm, even in 2D array, which I did not mention, Thanks a lot!